# Trigger TFS vNext Gated build with shelveset via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to trigger a TFS Gated vNext build, with a shelveset of my choosing. The code below successfully triggers the gated build, but it is not passing in the shelveset.

I am running TFS 2017 update 3.

```
[string]$TFSuser = "UserName"
[string]$TFSUserPAT = "PAT"

$body = '
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": "987",
            "sourceBranch":"Gated_2018-12-01_10.42.36.6232",
            "reason" : "checkInShelveset"
        } 
}
'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $TFSuser,$TFSUserPAT)))

$Uri = "https://TFSAddress.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/TN/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
write-host $buildresponse
```

Comment: The source branch should be in this way: `sourceBranch: "The shelveset name","The shelveset owner"`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried as suggested but it was invalid json, changed it to what is written in the build "sourceBranch": "Gated_2018-12-10_08.46.51.1114;NW\\PersonName", this still fails to build.

Comment: Try moving the source branch attribute outside of the definition.  Believe it should be at the same level as definition.